# Pycharm (Ubuntu) program not opening

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04/GNOME 3.8.4 on 15 MBP Duel  Boot.
I am new to Linux and Python(Pycharm ide)
I have downloaded the Pycharm "files" from the software center
but cannot run the program.The icon comes up in the side bar but when i click it nothing happens. I have tried "./" and only the code appers in "gedit" Please help  Oracle java is already installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi Pedro in ubuntu you need to install the files using the command prompt even if you downloaded the files you need to install them using command, unlike windows in linux when some software is downloaded you need to install them manually by using commands like sudo apt-get python install..
for further help you can consult http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-pycharm-3-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-linux-mint-17-pinguy-os-14-04-and-other-ubuntu-14-04-derivatives/

Comment: I have done this. I download the file from the site first. then i did sudo apt-get install pycharm. the sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get install update.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, after extracting your pycharm.tar.gz,
add the following in .bashrc file (which is in home folder itself, to view hidden files use `ctrl+h`)
`alias pycharm='~/tools/pycharm-4.0.6/bin/./pycharm.sh'`
**OR** In your case it might be,
`alias pycharm='~/Downloads/pycharm-4.0.6/bin/./pycharm.sh'`
And, then restart the terminal and type,

```
pycharm foldername
```

It should open the pycharm with given folder.